# how to design CPM algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, project-management

how to represent a graph with list data structure i have three class (Graph, Node, Edge) and would like to find the critical path in graph.

how to calculate

- ES : Earliest Start
- EC : Earliest Complete
- LS : Latest Start
- LC : Latest Complete

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative for storing the graph is the Boost Graph Library ([BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)). From what I see at wikipedia, the [critical path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method) is the longest path between two vertices. Furthermore it seems like finding the [longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is NP Complete for the general case but for a directed acyclic graph (DAG), which I think is your case, there are more efficient algorithms.

The longest path algorithm isn't in BGL but the DAG algorithm on wikipedia looks reasonably easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [quickgraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph/) library has classes for describing graphs, and a large number of graph algorithms, including [shortest path](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Shortest%20Path&referringTitle=Documentation). You may be able to do something like that.

What you seem to want, though, is actually more complex than a standard graph algorithm; it seems like you want the core of Microsoft Project available in a simple algorithm, and unfortunately it's not. You might consider buying a copy of project, and using it's COM API to do create your plan -- that may be the easy way, depending on your environment. I suspect you're going to have a whole bunch of work ahead of you, though.

Comment: I don't know what Qt is, but I don't see why not. It's a pure .net assembly you can use wherever.